# how to split a column based on gender

Tags: r, tidyr

Can we split a column using tidyr? Trying to avoid having to use a function.

From this

```
var1
Men.2001
Men.2002
Women.2001
Women.2002
```

To this

```
Gender   Year
Men      2001 
Men      2002
Women    2001
Women    2002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, var1, into=c('Gender', 'Year'))
```